# Issue: Jsoup to parse string with < followed by word

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm using Jsoup to parse the string which contains substring starts with < followed by a word to get the text but not getting text correctly

```
String input ="<p>testing with less than <string</p>";

String s = Jsoup.parse(input).text();
```

After extracting attribute text "testing with less than" is the result instead of **testing with less than <string**

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "<p>testing with less than <string</p>";
System.out.println(input);
```

> Output:

```
<p>testing with less than <string</p>
```

If we print the input we will get the entire string as shown.

```
String s1 = Jsoup.parse(input).text();
System.out.println(s1);// when we use method text()
```

> Output:

```
testing with less than
```

If we use the jsoup text() method, we get the plain text without HTML tags.

But still, we are not getting the entire input String because of the char "<".

the reason is justified in the following ex.

```
String s2 = Jsoup.parse(input).html();
System.out.println(s2);// when we use method html()
```

> Output:

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <p>testing with less than 
 <string></string> //the end tag is auto generated by the method
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

If we use the jsoup html() method, we get the entire formatted HTML code.

here we can clearly see that the word which is written after the char "<" in-between another HTML tag is automatically converted into an HTML tag.
(if we only write a start tag the end tag is automatically created whether it is valid or not)

this is the reason we are not getting entire input as shown in the first example